# How to use php-commitizen?

Tags: php, git

How to use **php-commitizen** to create commit messages following **Conventional Commits** specification?

I went to the repository [github-repository-of-lib](https://github.com/conventional-commits/php-commitizen) and followed the instructions for installing dependencies.

However, the **php vendor/bin/php-commitizen commit** command does not give the expected results.

[Image with typing command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fglzz.png)

How to do it ?

Comment: What are the expected results. What did you actually try?

Comment: @ChrisHaas **please see the image in the question**